# unable to use s3 trigger to transfer s3 objects to rds

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I have the lambda function code below that transfers objects from s3 buckets to AWS RDS database.

```
import json
import boto3
import pymysql 

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
def lambda_handler(event, context):

bucket_name = event["bucket"]
s3_file_name = event["object"]
resp = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=s3_file_name)

data = resp['Body']
rds_endpoint  = ""
username =  #username for RDS Mysql
password =  # RDS Mysql password
db_name = # RDS MySQL DB name
conn = None
try:
    conn = pymysql.connect(host=rds_endpoint, user=username, password=password, database=db_name)
except pymysql.MySQLError as e:
    print("ERROR: Unexpected error: Could not connect to MySQL instance.")

try:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(#db stuff)
    conn.commit()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    return 'Table not created!'
    
with conn.cursor() as cur:
    try:
        cur.execute(#db stuff)
        conn.commit()
        output = cur.execute()
    except:
        output = ("Entry not inputted! Error!")
    
print("Deleting the csv file from s3 bucket")

return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': 'Successfully uploaded!'
}
```

The code above works fine with this given test ev:

{
"bucket": "python-bucket",
"object": "bobmarley.mp3"
}

However, when I try to adapt it to the s3 bucket by changing the lines of code to below as seen in  this tutorial: https://www.data-stats.com/s3-data-ingestion-to-rds-through-lambda/

```
bucket_name = event["Records"][0]["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]
s3_file_name = event["Records"][0]["s3"]["object"]["key"]
```

I get this error:

```
[ERROR] TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 7, in lambda_handler
    bucket_name = event["Records"]["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]
```

Comment: Print out your event object to check its structure

Comment: Where would I be able to see the result of the print statement? @Marcin

Comment: Cloud watch logs for your function

Comment: Why your error says event["Records"]["s3"]["bucket"]["name but your code is different. This error is not from your code that you posted

Comment: Did you put the [0] index after ['Records']?